# how to add input placeholder django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

i wrote this from class then tried to add a placeholder to it

```
class ContactUs(forms.Form):
    your_email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter a valid email.')
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter your subject.')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'test'}), help_text='Enter your message.')
    cc = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

like this  and got list of error

```
class ContactUs(forms.Form):
    your_email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter a valid email.', attrs={'placeholder':'please enter a valid email'})
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter your subject.')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'test'}), help_text='Enter your message.')
    cc = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some thing like this:

```
q = forms.CharField(label='search', 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with a `EmailField` you can add a widget. To add more `attribute`, you can do it with a widget

```
your_email = forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter a valid email.', 
 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'please enter a valid email'}))
```